# Flutter animate background image on drag

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm trying to build a widget that allows the user to change a value by dragging. Similar to a Slider but different in the sense that the background is being dragged while the "value indicator" stays fixed.

I've got the functionality down but I'm not sure how to animate the background image properly to give it a sliding/dragging interaction.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SliderTest extends StatefulWidget {
@override
  _SliderTestState createState() => _SliderTestState();
}

class _SliderTestState extends State<SliderTest> {
double foo = 100.0;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text('SliderTest'),
  ),
  body: new Builder(builder: (context) {
    return new Center(
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text("$foo"),
          new Row(children: <Widget>[
            new Expanded(
              child: new GestureDetector(
                child: new Container(
                  height: 80.0,
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    image: new DecorationImage(
                      image: new AssetImage("resources/scale.png"),
                      repeat: ImageRepeat.repeatX
                    )
                  ),
                ),
                onHorizontalDragUpdate: (d) { 
                  if(d.primaryDelta >= 1.0 || d.primaryDelta <= - 1.0)
                  {
                    //print(d.primaryDelta); 
                    setState(() {
                      foo += d.primaryDelta;
                    });
                  }
                },
                )
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  })
);
}
}
```

How do I make the background image "move" in sync with the dragging?

Comment: put all your statefulwidget code please

Comment: @diegoveloper I added the full widget code, thanks for trying to help!

Comment: do you want to drag the image and move it? or do you want to drag in another container and move the image?

Comment: @diegoveloper I'm using a scale image like this (http://rajeshsetty.com/wp-content/uploads/Scale_4x.jpg) and want it to move to visualize the change in value, to give the user the feeling he is moving the scale and that changes the value. I'm not sure what the best way would be to animate this, I'm open for any recommendations on how to achieve this effect.

Comment: You could use the slider widget that flutter provide us : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/slider.dart    or you can customize that

Comment: No, I can't, I have a huge range but still need precision, the regular Slider widget won't work in that scenario. Now I'm trying to find out how to move the background image in concert with the drag gesture.

Comment: could you put your background image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if this is what you want, basically I put a `Transform` widget inside your `container` and inside it I put your image as `Image` widget.

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  class SliderTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
    _SliderTestState createState() => _SliderTestState();
  }

  class _SliderTestState extends State<SliderTest> {
  double foo = 100.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text('SliderTest'),
    ),
    body: new Builder(builder: (context) {
      return new Center(
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text("$foo"),
            new Row(children: <Widget>[
              new Expanded(
                child: new GestureDetector(
                  child: new Container(
                    height: 80.0,
                    child: new Transform.translate(
                      offset: new Offset(foo, 0.0),
                      child: new Image.asset("resources/scale.png"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onHorizontalDragUpdate: (d) { 
                    if(d.primaryDelta >= 1.0 || d.primaryDelta <= - 1.0)
                    {
                      //print(d.primaryDelta); 
                      setState(() {
                        foo += d.primaryDelta;
                      });
                    }
                  },
                  )
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    })
  );
  }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks man, that's almost perfect! The only problem left is that I need the scale to be continuous/infinite. The `Image.asset` despite a `repeat: ImageRepeat.repeatX` does not scale to it's parent's width but only to the initially visible part (i.e. 1 screenwidth). As soon as we translate it, the scale edge comes into view and just ends. But I guess I'm gonna open a new question for that. Thanks again!